# Merge emitted text change values with custom values

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I need a stream that emits text changes of an `EditText` (rx-binding) but I also need to be able to emit custom values that must be handled the same down the stream. I thought about merging a `PublishSubject` for the custom values with the `textChanges` Observable from rx-binding. Is there a way to achieve the same without merging? This is what I have so far.

```
PublishSubject<CharSequence> subject = PublishSubject.create();
Observable<CharSequence> textChanges = RxTextView.textChanges(mEditText); 

Observable.merge(subject, textChanges).flatMap(/*stuff*/)...
```

Comment: I think this is a perfect use case for merge. Even if there is another way I can't imagine it being more straightforward or readable than merge. Why are you looking for something else?

Comment: I thought I was misunderstanding the concept of subjects. Isn't it possible to make a single stream out of those two by letting the subject subscribe to textChanges and then reemit everything it emits + having the option to call onNext directly.

Comment: I guess you could do that, but that seems like reimplementing merge with a subject. And what if your second source wasn't a subject, what if you could wrap it nicely in a proper observable? Merge is what you need, you have to separate sources, but you want to expose them downstream as one.

Comment: "Isn't it possible to make a single stream out of those two by letting the subject subscribe to textChanges and then reemit everything it emits + having the option to call onNext directly" - Yes, it is. Why did you have to ask if you already know it?

Comment: "Yes, it is." Thank you